# Angular ternary operator to navigate user

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When a user land on a page, an object in the API contains a bool as:

```
  "Globals": [
    {
      "key": "HasDebitCard",
      "value": "True"
    }
  ]
```

So if the "value" is 'true' or 'false', it (the link) will navigate to the correct location. The code for this:

```
        <div class="toolTile col-md-3">
            <a ng-href="{{ ppt.Globals.value.True ? '#/claimEnter' : '#/clearSwipe' }}">
                <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/submiticon.svg" >
                <p>Submit a Claim for Reimbursement</p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

However, when the user click this link, it always goes to the same place, "clearSwipe" whether or not the "value" is set to 'True' or 'False'. In the DOM, it shows as navigating to the same place for both as:

```
<a ng-href="#/claimEnter" href="#/claimEnter">
```

Not sure why is it should render one way or the other. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, `ppt.Globals.value.True` will always return `undefined`. When you want to check if `ppt.Globals.value` is equal to True, use the following syntax `ppt.Globals.value == 'True'`

```
<div class="toolTile col-md-3">
    <a ng-href="{{ ppt.Globals[0].value == 'True' ? '#/claimEnter' : '#/clearSwipe' }}">
        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/submiticon.svg" >
        <p>Submit a Claim for Reimbursement</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: So revising it to that always returns clearSwipe and clearSwipe as shown in the DOM when it should show claimEnter since the value is true. Even if I log in with a user whos Globals.value equals 'False', it still shows clearSwipe and clearSwipe.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Is there anyway you can post a fiddle or codepen that reproduces the problem?

Comment: No, cause it is not a publically accessible API. Is like it is always going to the last one cause if I flip clearSwipe with claimEnter, it will go there. Code now is: ppt.Globals.value == 'True' ? '#/claimEnter' : '#/clearSwipe'

Comment: Does  `ppt.Globals.value == 'True'` return true, like you expect? It must not be, what is `ppt.Globals.value`?

Comment: What I mean is, if I change from true to false, it goes to last one.

Comment: What does `ppt.Globals.value` equal?

Comment: Yes, it does contain 'True'. Even tried lowercase 'true' thinking that may be an issue since what I am seeing is via Postman showing the JSON data returned for that logged in user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89963/discussion-between-anotherdev-and-mark).

Comment: Awesome @AnotherDev ...we figured it out. Because the data of the object was in an array as: ppt.Globals[0].value ? '#/claimEnter' : '#/clearSwipe'